# What's the thing between the pant legs?

Tags: minifigures, part-identification

What is the piece that holds the pant legs together called? Is there an "official<sup>1</sup>" name? Or is there just a commonly agreed on term?

[image]

<sup>1</sup>Official meaning something mentioned, even in passing, by Lego in some way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They are referred to as "Minifig Hips" almost everywhere: [partlink:970:4].

The LEGO Pick-a-brick service doesn't sell them without legs, and just refers to the whole construction as "Mini Figure Mini Lower Part":

[image: Pick-a-brick Lower Body Part]

Comment: Since that's utterly boring, I suggest we just start calling the thing what it actually is: a thong. Or a speedo.

Comment: @Joubarc Like the [Beach Troopers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Beach_trooper) from the LEGO Star Wars games?

Comment: And surely it's only a thong/speedo they are a different colour from the the legs, otherwise it's just waistband and flys/hips.

Comment: I just call it a belt

Comment: I once used the hips as rollers in a set, they look a bit like that with legs removed